# How to use str_replace without altering capitalization?

Tags: php, search, str-replace, capitalization

This is for a site search script. If I use str_ireplace, this will alter the capitalization of the search results. For example, if the query string is "search string" and a record containing "Search String" is found, the latter will lose its capitalization. Any way around this?

I need to incorporate highlighting for the search results.

The problem is not finding the string or getting it highlighted. I can use str_ireplace to accomplish this. But this will lose capitalization. What I want is to leave the capitalization intact, as well.

Comment: Why are you using a string replacement function when you don't want the string to be modified? Use a function that searches within the string like `stripos` instead of a function that's designed to modify your data. Or, post the code you're using so we can see exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: It's a search script that highlights the words submitted by user that appear in the search results. For str_replace it wasn't highlighting every word that showed up due to capitalization, but for str_ireplace it highlighted them all but they lost any capitalization that they had. Perhaps preg_match would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$haystack = 'Some text here.';
$str = preg_replace( "#(.*)(text)(.*)#i", '\1<b>\2</b>\3', $haystack );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [stripos](http://us.php.net/stripos) for search instead.

```
if ( stripos( $haystack, $needle ) !== false )
    echo $needle, ' found!';
```

Comment: I will need a highlighting functionality for the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Just use str_replace instead of str_ireplace.

Comment: Yes, but then "search string" will not pick up "Search String" or "Search string"

Comment: Try using preg_replace with the 'i' modifier.